# Is this valid Java code? My teacher claims it is, but I'm really not so sure

Tags: java, braces

Granted he didn't show us actual code here, just mentioned it, I found it extremely bizarre.

For example, according to what he said this is valid Java:

```
public class Person
{
    String Name;
    int Age;

    {
        //These two braces just chilling together - VALID? :O
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure - Give it a try. It is valid in most languages. Well, most that I have developed in. Just to make sure I tried it in the code I have open right now.

Comment: Why can't you compile it for yourself?

Comment: Fire up eclipse (or any other IDE) and type it out yourself - the IDE won't complain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes - it's the [instance initializer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6). You can also use it along with [anonymous subclasses](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) for [Double-Brace Initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).

Comment: Not with a semi-colon in between.  The { } are just a scope definition.

Comment: Nope, not when it's floating around in the class body like that - it's an empty instance initializer. Inside methods, then yes, it's a scope definition.

Comment: @vfilby: No, if it's a block within a class but not within a method or constructor, it's an instance initializer.

Comment: My bad, didn't look closely enough at the example. Thanks guys.